# Animating a sprite with frames cocos2dx 3.2

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

My animation is not working. It is showing me the frame that I mention while initializing the target sprite. Can anyone please tell me, what exactly did I miss? thank you.

```
SpriteFrameCache *spriteCache = SpriteFrameCache::getInstance();
spriteCache->addSpriteFramesWithFile("explode.plist", "explosion_rollv2.png");

Vector<SpriteFrame*> frames(22);
for (int i; i<= 22; i++)
{
        CCString *frame_name = CCString::createWithFormat("%d.png",i);
        auto frame = spriteCache->getSpriteFrameByName(frame_name->getCString());
        //frames->addObject(CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->spriteFrameByName(frame->getCString()));
        frames.pushBack(frame);

}

    auto blast_frame = Animation::createWithSpriteFrames(frames,0.1);
    blast_frame->setRestoreOriginalFrame(true);
    auto blast = Sprite::createWithSpriteFrameName("0.png");
    blast->setPosition(Vec2(visibleSize.width/2,visibleSize.height/2));
    this->addChild(blast,500);

    blast->runAction(RepeatForever::create(Animate::create(blast_frame)));
```

Answer (score 0):

To all those who are facing problem with this here's a link http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Sprite_Sheet_Animation